z3-python: How to correctly handle substitution of candidate functions in Z3 for LIA problems?
I'm new to z3, and have been working on a trying to solve LIA problems using Z3 (Z3 version 4.13.0 - 64 bit ) + python (3.12), and I think I need to substitute candidate expressions (which can be either expressions or integers) into a set of constraints.
What I'm really trying to do is generate python functions which could take numbers of arguments e.g. x and y, and test them with z3 to see if they satisfy the constraints of the problem and are valid. These generated python functions could return an Int e.g.
def func_1(*args): 
    return 1

or something slightly more complex e.g.
def max_function(*args):
    if len(args) != 2:
        raise ValueError("max_function expects exactly 2 arguments.")
    x, y = values
    return If(x <= y, y, x)

A sample problem (but not limited to just this one) I'm trying to solve is the max of 2 ints:
(set-logic LIA)
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(assert (= (f x y) (f y x)))
(assert (and (<= x (f x y)) (<= y (f x y))))

As far as I can see, I need to substitute the candidate functions into the constraints in the solver.
From previous answers I've understood that this approach is possibly the only way to do the following:
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
needs to become the following for func_1
(define-fun f (Int Int) Int(1))
and needs to become for func_2
(define-fun f (Int Int) Int (ite (<= x y) y x))
as I can't find a way to redefine the function i.e. go from declare-fun to define-fun, from what I've gathered, I need to specifically use python functions (not as z3 "Functions"), and substitute the candidate function/expression into the constraints. Which works for simple problems e.g. if I hardcode it, but I cannot seem to get it working for more complex ones in a more dynamic way i.e. with different constraints or numbers of variables (I've searched stackoverflow and tried to also incorporate a previous question's solution here). I've tried many different ways of doing this so can only assume that it is a fundamental misunderstanding. Here is one iteration that fails to substitute correctly for the commutativity constraint in the sample problem as a reproducible example:
def make_expression(possible_expression):
    if is_expr(possible_expression):
        return possible_expression
    elif isinstance(possible_expression, int):
        return IntVal(possible_expression)
    else:
        raise Exception("Cannot convert: %s" % possible_expression.__repr__())

def substitute_constraints(constraints: Collection[z3.ExprRef], func: z3.FuncDeclRef,
                           candidate_expression: typing.Union[z3.FuncDeclRef, z3.QuantifierRef, typing.Callable, int, z3.IntNumRef]) -> typing.List[z3.ExprRef]:
    def reconstruct_expression(expr: z3.ExprRef) -> z3.ExprRef:
        if is_app(expr) and expr.decl() == func:
            new_args = [reconstruct_expression(arg) for arg in expr.children()]
            if callable(candidate_expression):
                return candidate_expression(*new_args)
            elif isinstance(candidate_expression, (FuncDeclRef, QuantifierRef)):
                return candidate_expression(*new_args)
            else:
                return make_expression(candidate_expression)
        elif is_app(expr):
            new_args = [reconstruct_expression(arg) for arg in expr.children()]
            return expr.decl()(*new_args)
        else:
            return expr

    if isinstance(candidate_expression, (int, z3.IntNumRef)):
        substitution_pairs = [(func, make_expression(candidate_expression))]
    elif callable(candidate_expression):
        substitution_pairs = [(func, lambda *args: candidate_expression(*[make_expression(arg) for arg in args]))]
    else:
        substitution_pairs = [(func, candidate_expression)]

    return [substitute(c, *substitution_pairs) for c in constraints]

x, y = Ints('x y')
expr = x + y

def functionFromExpr(args, expr):
    return lambda *fargs: substitute(expr, *zip(args, [make_expression(e) for e in fargs]))

f = functionFromExpr([x, y], expr)
# These work ok
print(f(x, y))          # Should print: x + y
print(f(x, IntVal(4)))  # Should print: x + 4
print(f(IntVal(3), IntVal(4)))  # Should print: 3 + 4

# This does not work
x, y = Ints('x y')
f = Function('f', IntSort(), IntSort(), IntSort())

commutativity_constraint = f(x, y) == f(y, x)
print("Original commutativity constraint:")
print(commutativity_constraint)
def func_2(a, b):
    return If(a >= b, a, b)

substituted_constraints = substitute_constraints([commutativity_constraint], f, func_2)
for constraint in substituted_constraints:
    print(constraint)

substituted_constraints = substitute_constraints([commutativity_constraint], f, 42)
for constraint in substituted_constraints:
    print(constraint)

I usually get some variant of:
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Z3 invalid substitution, expression pairs expected.
I've tried using z3.Substitute, z3.Substitute_funs, z3.substitute_vars etc as documented here
I would like to avoid trying to do this with string manipulation in SMT-LIB if possible (generating candidate programs and resetting the solver and parsing the problem from a string), as I understand the recommendation is to not mix SMT-LIB and python i.e. stick to one or the other, and to try and use python functions for this kind of problem.
Please let me know if any of the assertions or assumptions I have made are incorrect (I've gathered them from previous answers along the way, though I may have misunderstood), hopefully that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You typically don't need these sorts of substitution tricks; unless you're building proof-tools on top of z3 itself. You can simply define the functions in Python, max for instance, and prove it's commutative. You don't need to define it in SMTLib. (You can, but there's no need.) But perhaps your goal is something else?

Hi Alias, thanks for your reply. My overall goal is to make a configurable program synthesis engine; i.e. take in an LIA problem (I've settled on as a string but I guess this doesn't have to be the case), defined in SyGuS, convert to SMT-LIB, then use Z3 as an SMT solver to perform CEGIS e.g. with basic enumerative search for candidate functions and try out different algorithms these. I've just got stuck on this point of trying to substitute the candidate function into the z3 solver. If there is a better way to do this overall or if you would take an alternative approach, please let me know.

I've created a gist with the first few iterations on trying to make this work here so you can see what I was trying to do, I've been iterating on that, trying to make it more dynamic i.e. to be able to handle any LIA problem, not just max of 2 ints as given here.

I see. Well; building such a system is a whole lot of work. But you're in luck; CVC5 comes with direct support for SyGus. I recommend starting with CVC5 itself instead of Z3; use their facilities, and see if that does the trick for you. Only look for building your own solution if for some reason CVC5 doesn't work for you. Start here: https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ajreynol/cav19b.pdf and also https://cvc5.github.io/docs/cvc5-1.0.2/examples/sygus-grammar.html?highlight=sygus

I've partially implemented something similar in CVC5, either way I have to parse out the constraints, but switched back to z3 as the api was a bit less friendly , maybe I'll switch back and give it a go again. Thanks for the paper/reference and advice.
I've successfully converted between SyGuS and SMT-LIB ok, was just wondering if there was a better way to attempt this in regards to testing candidates, maybe string manipulation is the way to go then, without substitution. I've also tried enabling macro-finder and just providing a definition for the function to no avail.

Manipulating z3 expressions in z3 is definitely possible, but it's neither easy, nor the API is entirely stable. I think CVC5's grammar based generation facility is your best bet, and I believe CVC5 guys are actively supporting it. (So, you can get support from them if you run into issues.) Z3 is just not the best choice for this problem, compared to what CVC5 provides. Essentially, you'd have to replicate all the work CVC5 folks did, which is not an insignificant undertaking.

Ok thanks for your advice, I'll switch to cvc5 and see how it goes.
